# Custom PHP contact form in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm reusing some code I have on static sites for a contact form.

So I imagine my problem is something wordpress related.

I have left my other PHP code in there incase something is causing problems.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I feel it is probably the index.php part in the form. because now my links have to include the extension for the domain.

www.richardmiddleton.me/growthitude-wordpress is the site.

Thanks in advance

PHP

```
<?php /* Template Name: home */ ?>


<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $from = 'Form on site';
        $to = 'Richard@richardemailaddress.me'; // BUSINESS EMAIL ADDRESS
        $subject = 'Message from form';

        $body ="From: $name\n Number: $phone\n Message:\n $message";
        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['phone'] || !filter_var($_POST['phone'])) {
            $errphone = 'Please enter a valid phone number';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errPhone && !$errMessage) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
         header("Location: success.html");
         exit();
    } else {
        header("Location: fail.html");
        exit();
    }
}
    }
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php the_content(); ?>
```

HTML

```
<form id="contact-form" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">

                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">


                                <!-- Form Name -->

                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required="required" name="name" placeholder="NAME (REQUIRED)" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
                                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- END Form Name -->

                            </div>


                            <div class="col-md-6">


                                <!-- Form Number -->

                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" required="required" name="phone" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER (REQUIRED)" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']); ?>">
                                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errPhone</p>";?>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- END Form Number -->

                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- END ROW 1 FORM -->



                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">


                                <!-- Form Message -->

                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder="TELL US ABOUT YOUR CLEANING CARE NEEDS" name="message"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?></textarea>
                                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- END Form Message -->


                            </div>


                            <!-- Form Submit -->

                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="SEND" class="btn btn-success btn-md">
                            </div>

                            <!-- END Form Submit -->


                        </div>


                        <!-- Form Required -->

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <?php echo $result; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </form>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: No, just no email arriving. Will try Ivijan's help when I'm back at it.

Answer (score 0):

Generaly you need to use `wp_mail()` instead of `mail()` function. Second thing is that WordPress have some defined POST informations and you can't use simple post name fields.

you have post names like name, email, message, submit etc.

**You can't use that.**.

Replace that with some prefix like `bzx_name`, `bzx_email`, `bzx_message` etc. and also in POST replace like `$_POST['bzx_name']`.

Also remove `index.php` from `action` attribute inside `form` if you just refresh page or provide full URL if you need to go on another one.

This will work fine after fix.